# Google Analytics implementation in shopify public app

Tags: reactjs, iframe, google-analytics, next.js, shopify-app

We have a shopify embedded public app(An embedded app is rendered inside iframe) created using node , next js and react js.
We have requirement the google analytics in our application.

We are the facing the following problems when implementing the same

1. Custom events not being send to the Google Analytics on triggering from the component level.
   We are not getting any console errors and call is reaching the analytics library and is not
   send from there.
2. Sometimes when the page is refreshed and reloaded, The active users in GA dashboard appears to be zero.

I am using the gtag.js implementation and the below is the code snippet:

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add the `gtag.js` implementation code. Mind adding that to the question?